# C# Compiler warning (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to use Microsoft Depency Injection, to load my settings. Which is working entirely as I want it to. But I keep getting compiler warnings and no matter what I do I cannot make them go away.

Which is honestly kinda p... me off, as I consider a compiler warning the same as having an error.

My initial code was this

```
public static IServiceProvider Kernel;
```

Which causes the warning
Code: CS8618
Description: Non-nullable field 'Kernel' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.

This I then did, as VS pushes it as proper practices. But that only made things waaay worse.

The first time I try to use Kernel I get another warning (I'm using Avalonia)

```
   public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            LoadAndSetupDI();
            var settings = Kernel.GetRequiredService<ProgramSettings>();
            if (settings == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("settings = null");
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
```

The warning is
Code: CS8604
Description: Possible null reference for parameter 'provider' in [read the GetRequiredService call] ... (IServiceProvider provider)

I am not using the name provider anywhere.

The last thing the Method LoadAndSetupDI() does is throwing an exception if the Kernel is still null. So obviously Kernel can never be null, because if that was the case the program would downright hard crash.

So the following check for null is completely redundant. The second check is only because the compiler warning.

Does anyone know how to solve this compiler warning?

Comment: A [mcve] would help since I don’t know why that field should be static or why it cannot be set up in a constructor to remove the warning without using nullables

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem to me. Why are you trying to create a `IServiceProvider` in a static field? If you are using DI to load services, then *all* services should be loaded via DI. None of them should need to refer to a static field to load additional services. Though you could turn `Kernel` into a static property which throws if the backing field is null.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have a non-nullable field so you should make sure that it has a value when the constructor completes. Otherwise you have a non-nullable field whose value is `null`, which is a contradiction. Either make the field nullable:

```cs
public static IServiceProvider? Kernel;
```

or be sure to set that field in the constructor. I'm not sure but the fact that the field is `static` may mean that you need to set it in a `static` constructor.

If you make the field nullable then you need to account for that later, i.e. accessing a member via a nullable field will trigger a warning that a null reference may occur. If you know that the reference will not be `null` then you can specify that like so:

```cs
var settings = Kernel!.GetRequiredService<ProgramSettings>();
```

It sounds like you probably ought to do some reading on nullable reference types, which is a fairly new concept. I'm not exactly an expert myself but I've been learning lately.